# EntityObject can not be initialized with null EntityInfo for Guest User

Tags: apex, trigger, community, visual-workflow, email-alert

I have created a flow that allows external users (Guest User Profile) to submit a case status update.

My final step which is an email alert in the flow continues to fail with the following error message:

```
 EntityObject can not be initialized with null EntityInfo
```

Can guest users not access email alerts?

Here is the template being used, I am not sure if that also has anything to do with this.

```
Case #: {!Case.CaseNumber}
Primary Contact: {!Case.Contact}
Owner: {!Case.OwnerFullName}
Status: {!Case.Status}
Subject: {!Case.Subject}
Description:
{!Case.Description}



{!Case.Thread_Id}
```